# Parse Dictionary in JSON using DataContractJsonSerializerSettings w/o using header class

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm parsing a JSON string into a list of items. The json text has the items organized as a dictionary under a parent item "material". The below code works. Is there a better way to do this where I don't need the MaterialHeader class?

```
public class Material
{
    public Material()
    {
        E = 209000;
        nu = 0.3;
    }
    public double E;
    public double nu;
    public double ultimateStrength; // new
    public double enduranceLimit; // new
    public double yieldStrength;  // new
    public double density; // new
    public double sB0; //  new
    public String itemNumber; // new

    public string form; // not needed for FEA
    public string description; // not needed for FEA
    public double cost; // not needed for FEA
}

public class MaterialHeader
{
    public Dictionary<String,Material> material;
}

    public List<Material> Materials(String companyID) {

        var response = "{ \"material\": { \"PM00000050\": { \"cost\": \"1.6\",\"E\": \"209000\",\"yieldStrength\": \"306\",\"description\": \"1045\",\"form\": \"Plate\",\"nu\": \"0.3\",\"enduranceLimit\": \"256\",\"sB0\": \"409\",\"ultimateStrength\": \"570\",\"density\": \"7.85\"},\"PM00000051\": { \"cost\": \"1.62\",\"E\": \"209000\",\"yieldStrength\": \"270\",\"description\": \"4140\",\"form\": \"Plate\",\"nu\": \"0.3\",\"enduranceLimit\": \"243\",\"sB0\": \"409\",\"ultimateStrength\": \"540\",\"density\": \"7.85\"},\"PM00000055\": { \"cost\": \"1.61\",\"E\": \"209000\",\"yieldStrength\": \"306\",\"description\": \"K1045\",\"form\": \"Bar\",\"nu\": \"0.3\",\"enduranceLimit\": \"256\",\"sB0\": \"409\",\"ultimateStrength\": \"570\",\"density\": \"7.85\"},\"PM00000056\": { \"cost\": \"1.62\",\"E\": \"209000\",\"yieldStrength\": \"270\",\"description\": \"K4140\",\"form\": \"Bar\",\"nu\": \"0.3\",\"enduranceLimit\": \"243\",\"sB0\": \"409\",\"ultimateStrength\": \"540\",\"density\": \"7.85\"} }}";

    DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

        var serializer2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MaterialHeader), settings);
        var ms2 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(response));

        var output1 = new MaterialHeader();
        try
        {
            output1 = (MaterialHeader)serializer2.ReadObject(ms2);
        }
        catch (SerializationException exp)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }

        var output2 = new List<Material>();
        foreach ( var item in output1.material)
        {
            item.Value.itemNumber = item.Key; // Set the item number
            output2.Add(item.Value);
        }

        return output2;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need some tricks just to avoid it. Use it as it is.

Comment: You could deserialize it as a `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String,Material>>`.  But your code looks fine as it is.